# How to prove geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-topology, geometric-progressions

The given series is: $$6+3*2^{1-n}$$

Prove that this series is geometric progression. What is $a_n$ in this series? And also show if the series is convergent.

I tried to:

So we know that the sum of n terms in geometric progression is: $$\frac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1}$$
I created the equation:  $$\frac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1} = 6+3*2^{1-n} $$

The thing here is, that there is more than one variable. So I don't know what $q$ is and also what $a_1$ is. This is when things get difficult. To show that the series is convergent I know that I would have to use: $$-1<q<1$$, and for the $a_n$ term I would use $$a_n=a_1*q^{n-1}$$ But how to get $a_1$ and $q$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_n = 6+3\cdot 2^{1-n}$$
$$S_{n-1} = 6+3\cdot 2^{2-n}$$

$$a_n = S_n - S_{n-1}=3\cdot (2^{1-n}-2^{2-n})=3(2^{1-n})(1-2)=(-3)\cdot 2^{1-n}=-6\cdot 2^{-n}$$